# Recognize integers from string

Tags: c, parsing

I want to take a string from the user and convert it to an `int` array. If the character is `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`, nothing will change. If there is a charecter 1 it will be the integer 1. But it is not working correctly: if I enter `5+5`, it gives `5 -2`. How can I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main(){

     char x[]={};
     printf("?\n");
     scanf("%s",x);
     int i,k=0;
     int y[7];
     int num=0;


     for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){
          if(x[i] != '+' && x[i] != '-' && x[i] != '/' && x[i] != '*' ){
                  num= (num*10)  +((int)x[i]-48);        
          }
          else if(x[i] == '+' || x[i] == '-' || x[i] == '/' || x[i] == '*'){

              y[k] = num;
              num=0;

              k = k+1;


          }
          else if(x[i] == '\n'){
               y[k] = num;

               num=0;
               k++;
               break;     
          }                   
     }

     for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){
             printf("%d ",y[i]);        
     }     

}
```

Comment: "char x[]={}; " I'm surprised it compiles and doesn't segfault at your scanf. You should write "char x[100]".

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant since it would seem the poster isn't too C-saavy based on the odd definition of x you're pointing out, you might want to consider telling him more than "char x[100];" -- things like why (in order to allocate space to scan into), what 100 means (in case 100 bytes isn't enough for him, or if he knows it's way too much, etc.), and perhaps ways to use scanf such that he knows he cannot possibly overflow the 100 byte buffer you suggested.

Comment: I think he is writting bytes in his application, and it doesn't segfault because of that.

Answer (score 1):

`ctype.h` has `int isdigit ( int c );` which returns `0` if the character is not a number and non-zero value if it is.